# Sails (1.2.3) gives plaintext 'Not found' (404) when main entry point is moved to a subfolder, how do I fix?

Tags: node.js, sails.js

My sails.js project is also an electron.js project, and for packaging I'll need to move my main entry point to a subfolder (thanks, electron-packager) ... but here's what happens.

Before moving the entry point to a subfolder, my app works under all methods of launching, namely:

- `sails lift`
- `node .`
- `electron .`
- `electron-forge start`

Launching with the main entry point in a subfolder gives these results:

- `sails lift` works perfectly, I can use the app 100%
- All ***other*** methods of launching the app e.g. `node .` however, misbehaves.

**"Misbehaves" = 404 plaintext "Not Found"**

When I say "misbehaves" -- I'm not sure the extent of the problem. Sails lifts, it complains that it can't find its session secret, and when I load the page in a browser I get a **404 with a plaintext "Not found"** message. I suspect the engine has launched but it hasn't found its app files.

Troubleshooting suggestions or a solution would be greatly appreciated.

Note that I did update package.json's "main" attribute.

Here is my [package.json](https://github.com/NathanHawks/FictionDB/blob/master/package.json)

Comment: it will be better if you can show your package json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround.

1. Move the "real" main entry script to the top-level folder of the project (same folder as `package.json`).
2. Create a new script and put it in the subfolder, e.g. `app/launcher.js`. It only needs to contain one line: `require('../app.js');` (presuming your "real" main entry script is `app.js`).
3. Update `package.json` 's `main` node to point at `app/launcher.js`

I also reported this as a bug to sails.js, but they re-flagged it as a question. :-/